# How to reshape a numpy array to a new ndarraw with a kernel of surrounding pixels

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array, which could vary in size (I'll get to that in a second), that I want to reshape so that each point in the array is a kernal of the original array.

So, lets say I start with the array:

```
np.arange(81).reshape(9,9)

>>> array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
       [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
       [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
       [45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53],
       [54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62],
       [63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71],
       [72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80]])
```

But now I'd like to reshape this array so that each "point" in this array isn't an integer value, but itself a small NxM array. BUT, the part I'm having trouble with is having the smaller arrays overlap. So I'd like it to look something like:

```
array(
[[[[ 0  1  2]   [[ 1  2  3]   [[ 2  3  4]
   [ 9 10 11]    [10 11 12]    [11 12 13]
   [18 19 20]]   [19 20 21]]   [20 21 22]]]
```

So as you can see there is overlap in those arrays. I don't know how to use numpy reshape methods to achieve this. The closest I've come is  to use:

```
arr = np.arange(81).reshape(9,9)
kernalized = np.swapaxes(arr.reshape(3,3,3,-1),1,2)

>>> array(
[[[[ 0  1  2]   [[ 3  4  5]   [[ 6  7  8]
   [ 9 10 11]    [12 13 14]    [15 16 17]
   [18 19 20]]   [21 22 23]]   [24 25 26]]])
```

This achieves the correct shape! So I feel like I'm on the right path. But there isn't overlap. Anybody have any ideas I can try out?
As added cherry on top, the arrays could be different sizes so ideally whatever code I come up with can handle this, but this isn't the biggest issue because the arrays are quite large and simply shaving off a few rows or columns to make it divisible by 3 is fine for my purposes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `as_strided`:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

strides = a.strides
window = 3 

out = as_strided(a, ((a.shape[0]-window+1),(a.shape[1]-window+1),window,window), 
               (strides[1], strides[1]) + a.strides 
              ).reshape(-1, window, window)

print(out[:3])
```

Output:

```
[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 9 10 11]
  [18 19 20]]

 [[ 1  2  3]
  [10 11 12]
  [19 20 21]]

 [[ 2  3  4]
  [11 12 13]
  [20 21 22]]]
```

Comment: Thank you, yes this does look about what I'm looknig for. Just to point out that  on the second row of the out variable should be strides[0], strides[1] if you want it to move through the entire array. Otherwise the strides repeat themselves.